# Truncamento aprimorado de strings

Tags: php, interpolação-de-string

Estava eu revisando uns códigos antigos quando encontrei [uma função](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1b42441c9ff6a7ec7c06) que "trunca" uma determinada string depois de X caracteres:

Essa função, diferentemente de um [substr()](http://www.php.net/substr) simples, não deixa o desenvolvedor em situações constrangedoras como essa:

```
$str = 'Então, Chapeuzinho Vermelho decide tomar no cantinho, bem escondida, uma lata de leite condensado.';

var_dump( substr( $str, 45 ) . '...' );
```

Que resultaria em:

> Então, Chapeuzinho Vermelho decide tomar no c...

Fica chato... :p

Já com essa função aprimorada, uma declaração como essa:

```
var_dump( truncate( $str, 45, 'after' ) );
```

Resultaria em:

> Então, Chapeuzinho Vermelho decide tomar no cantinho,...

Bem melhor :D

Porém, eu encontrei dois problemas, mínimos, quanto ao terceiro cenário coberto pela função, o qual adiciona as reticências no meio da string, assim:

> Então, Chapeuzinho Vermelho ... cantinho, bem escondida, uma lata de leite condensado.

O primeiro deles é que, como visto no exemplo acima, as reticências (ou outro caractere/*substring* configurado) não são adicionadas próximo ao meio da string como deveria.

Já o segundo problema só é perceptível com algumas strings específicas, muitas vezes curtas, como essa:

```
$str = 'Eu coloquei meu cabo de enxada no seu curral';

var_dump( truncate( $str, 35, 'center' ) );
```

Isso produziria:

> Eu coloquei meu cabo ... o seu curral

Ou seja, a letra **n** de **no seu** foi indevidamente suprimida.

Eu até consegui solucionar esse problema subtraindo 1 (um) do `strlen( $append )` de **$end**.

Mas enquanto isso soluciona para frases pequenos, corrompe para frases longas, fazendo com que o exemplo da Chapeuzinho Vermelho passasse a resultar em:

> Então, Chapeuzinho Vermelho ...##cantinho, bem escondida, uma lata de leite condensado.

Isto é, com um espaço a mais depois a string inserida (antes de **cantinho**) no que seria o *quase* meio da string (substitui por *hashes* para ficar visível).

É um problema bobo de *offset*, mas eu não consegui solucionar da forma correta.

Por hora, um *workaround* foi substituir quaisquer espaços duplos na string antes de retornar, mas se possível consertar ao invés de remediar, melhor.

Alguma idéia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, levei o caso [pro SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551290) e obtive uma resposta fantástica que não apenas soluciona o problema mas, a meu pedido, soluciona de forma balanceada.

Ou seja, além de interpolar um string configurável entre duas *substrings* o mais próximo do meio da string original, não quebra as palavras no meio e ainda faz com que a string resultante tenha comprimento bastante próximo daquele desejado:

```
/**
 * Truncates a string at specified length without breaking words
 *
 * @param string $string
 *  The string to truncate
 *
 * @param integer $length
 *  The expected length after truncated
 *
 * @param string|optional $delimiter
 *  The string interpolated in the middle of string
 *
 * @return string
 *  Truncated string
 */
public static function truncate( $string, $length, $delimiter = '(...)' ) {

    if( strlen( $string ) <= $length ) return $string;

    $delimiter = sprintf( ' %s ', trim( $delimiter ) );

    $len = (int) ( ( $length - strlen( $delimiter ) ) / 2 );

    // Separate the output from wordwrap() into an array of lines

    $segments = explode( "\n", wordwrap( $string, $len ) ) ;

    /**
     * Last element's length is less than half $len, append
     * words from the second-last element
     */
    $end = end( $segments );

    /**
     * Add words from the second-last line until the end is at least
     * half as long as $length
     */
    if( strlen( $end ) <= ( $length / 2 ) && count( $segments ) > 2 ) {

        $prev = explode( ' ', prev( $segments ) );

        while( strlen( $end ) <= ( $length / 2 ) ) {
            $end = sprintf( '%s %s', array_pop( $prev ), $end );
        }
    }

    return reset( $segments ) . $delimiter . trim( $end );
}
```

Não é a toa que o cara tem 141k de reputação :p

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução, mas que eu não acho muito eficiente, porém funcional seria:

```
function trucar($texto, $qtdCaracteres) {
    $string = strip_tags($texto);
    if (strlen($texto) > $qtdCaracteres) {
        while (substr($text, $qtdCaracteres, 1) <> ' ' && ($qtdCaracteres < strlen($texto))){
            $qtdCaracteres++;
        };
    };
    return substr($texto,0,$qtdCaracteres) . '...';
}
```

Nesse caso estamos procurando por um espaço depois do intervalo determinado, assim somente corta a string quando houver um espaço.

E a utilização:

```
$texto = "Teste de escrita de texto.";

echo trucar($texto, 15);
```

O resultádo será: **Teste de escrita...**

Fonte: http://www.sergiotoledo.com.br/tutoriais/programacao-php/criando-resumo-em-php

Comment: A sua solução adiciona as reticências no final da string e felizmente isso eu já tenho. Estou procurando uma que encurte a string o mais próximo possível do tamanho desejado, mas coloque as reticências no meio da string, resultando num pedacinho do começo dela, as reticências e depois um pedacinho do final dela (vide último exemplo)